# Format method on String

Tags: java

When I am writing this code

```
float f=56.7876f;
System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f",f));
```

the output is: 56.787601470947

but, when I am writing this code

```
System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f",56.7876));
```

the output is: 56.787600000000

Why in both the cases different outputs are being printed despite of the fact that the functionality of both the code is same?

Comment: because `56.7876` is a `double` literal. Try `System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f",56.7876f));`

Comment: Do you want to know why 56.787601470947265625 is the single precision floating point representation of 56.7876 and why 56.7875999999999976353137753903865814208984375 is the double precision floating point representation of 56.7876?  See http://floating-point-gui.de/ and http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`System.out.print(String.format("%32.12f",56.7876));` It is returning 12 char fractional part filling with 0 and it consider 56.7876 as double.

you can refer following link:- https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples

Comment: This does not answer the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

[All floating point numbers without some suffix are `double` literals in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2). This is the reason why

```
float ohNoes = 56.7876;
```

will produce a compiler error (`java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float`).

So If you write

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%32.12f",56.7876));
        System.out.println(String.format("%32.12f",56.7876f));
    }
}
```

You can see the diference. The first prints the `double` literal `56.7876`, while the second prints the nearest `float`-representation of `56.7876`.

Answer (score 0):

The `String.format( format, Object... args)` eventually calls :

```
private void print(float value, Locale l) throws IOException {
    print((double) value, l);
}
```

for `float` literals.  See in `Formatter$FormatSpecifier.java` in [`Formatter.java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

the value `56.787601470947` that you see is because the float literal `56.7876f` is casted to a double as shown in above method.

If you print the following :

```
float f = 56.7876f;
System.out.println( (double)f );
```

you will see same value : `56.787601470947`

Comment: @Turing85 I didn't mean it as float literal. 56.7876f is.

Comment: Then append an `f` do make it a `float` literal.

Comment: @Turing85 Please see the line `because the float literal 56.7876f`